# Function - Compilation error. Line 9: no viable alternative at character '{'

Tags: function, scripting, pine-script

I am trying to write a trading strategy in Pine Script, but I am getting a compilation error on line 9. The error message states that there is "no viable alternative at character '{'". I have tried adding the keyword "function" before the function name, but the error still persists. The goal is to have the code look at the volatility of the market with MACD, 200 EMA and overall volume with in an hour to determine a safe amount to invest during that period. Can someone please help me fix this error and make my code compile successfully?

```
function calcTradeAmount(v) => {
  tradeAmount = money * (v / 100)
  return tradeAmount
}
```

If the function works properly my if(long) and if(shorts) should be able to pull a different number each time. I don't want to have 1 trade be the entire portfolio each time.

Sample:

```
if (long)
tradeAmount = calcTradeAmount(volatility)
entryPrice = low
```

Answer (score 0):

calcTradeAmount(v) =>
tradeAmount = money * (v / 100)
tradeAmount

Comment: Could you format your code and also show how it differs from the `function` that you were using in your question..? It is a little unclear as to what the fix actually is... What happened to the `{...}` and the `return`?

Comment: 1. The code must be highlighted. 
2. It is necessary to provide a description of the code with some details